# Flutter: pod not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I am having trouble setting up the pod in my Mac M1 chip.

I downloaded Xcode from App Store and then entered the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

But when I run the second command -  sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch, I get the following error:

```
objc[5579]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ef6bdeb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103db44f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5579]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ef6bdf00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103db4548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5579]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ef6bdf50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103db4598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5579]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ef6bdfa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103db45e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5579]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ef6bdff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103db4638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5579]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ef6be040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103db4688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I do not understand why I get this error.

After that I run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

To which it shows that gem installed.

But after that when I enter pod install or any other command related to pod it says:

```
zsh: command not found: pod
```

And also when I run flutter doctor it says:

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
```

If I have already installed CocoaPods why flutter doctor shows it is not installed and why is the pod now working.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Make sure that `pod` is in the command line search path

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```